# sonar.jdbc.url parameter overwritten in sonar-runner and jenkins

Tags: jdbc, parameters, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a problem using Jenkins and Sonar. Here is my setup: a main linux server hosting **Jenkins** and **Sonar** and a windows vm to build a project. The windows vm is configured as a Jenkins **slave**, and the job I defined can successfully get project source and perform a ant build. But it fails at running Sonar analysis using sonar runner.

The error raised says "java.sql.SQLException: No database selected" and while looking at the console output, I see twice the jdbc url parameter:

```
... "-Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3306/sonar?userUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8" ... -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3306 ...
```

So obviously the second parameter is the one used, and is missing the database name. If I change the second parameter and launch it from command line, it works fine.

The question is: why my parameter is overwritten and how can I change it?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several parameter modifications, my fix was simply to restart the Jenkins salve agent... As this is not a complete explanation, anyone with more details is welcome to post another answer.